# How to have no indentation after \maketitle?

Tags: indentation, titles

By default, the paragraph starts after `\maketitle` will be indented. But, I do not need the indentation after `\maketitle`.

Could anyone suggest us how to control this in the template. I have attached the screenshot for your reference

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Title page}

\author{Author name}

\maketitle

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have only one title, you could just add `\noindent` before the first line.

Answer (score 3):

In your example the following works. But it will fail if you use the titlepage option. I also didn't test it with every class ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\appto\@maketitle{\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{Title page}

\author{Author name}

\maketitle

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\noindent` right before the first paragraph after `\maketitle`. This method requires no extra packages, and it should work with just about any document class, i.e., any document class that doesn't modify the meaning of `\noindent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{Title page}
\author{Author name} 
\maketitle

\noindent  % insert this instruction before the first text paragraph
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could insert

```
\parindent 0 pt
```

in your preamble

Comment: This will remove indentation from all paragraphs, not just the one following the title as requested.  Anyway, this type of change should usually be combined with adding some vertical space between paragraphs, in which case the `parskip` package is the way to go.

Comment: The syntax is also not recommended for use with LaTeX. Better use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`.