# Avoiding indent after \maketitle in twocolumn article

Tags: titles, indentation, two-column, article

How can I automatically avoid the indent in the first paragraph of a `twocolumn` article.cls document with a title?  Note that the document I am writing has a custom `\@maketitle`. For example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
% The following works in onecolumn mode, but not twocolumn
\def\@maketitle{\begin{center}\@title\end{center}\noindent}
% Can also place \aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
% at the end of macro (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250327/).
\makeatother

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
This paragraph starts with an indent (unless you manually place a \verb|\noindent| at 
its start).

\section{Section Title}
In contrast \verb|\section{...}| does not produce an indent.
\end{document}
```

produces a document with indentation at the start of the first paragraph (right after `\maketitle`). I would like to eliminate that indent by making some changes to the preamble (as opposed to inserting a `\noindent` in the main document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this here should work:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\appto\maketitle{\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}{}{}
\makeatother
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This paragraph starts with an indent (unless you manually place a \verb|\noindent| at
its start).

\section{Section Title}
In contrast \verb|\section{...}| does not produce an indent.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine `\maketitle` to include that `\noindent` at its end:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
% The following works in onecolumn mode, but not twocolumn
\def\@maketitle{\begin{center}\@title\end{center}\noindent}
% Can also place \aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
% at the end of macro (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250327/).
\makeatother

\edef\maketitle{\unexpanded\expandafter{\maketitle\noindent}}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
This paragraph starts with an indent (unless you manually place a \verb|\noindent| at 
its start).

\section{Section Title}
In contrast \verb|\section{...}| does not produce an indent.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be far better to use `\@afterheading` as otherwise you can not leave a blank line before `\maketitle` which is weird

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I use `\@afterheading` in this situation? (I tried replacing `\noindent` with it, but that did not work.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you mean after `\maketitle` don't you? :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please post the code. The idiomatic `\edef\maketitle{\unexpanded\expandafter{\maketitle\@afterheading}}` doesn't work.

Comment: I feel that my question is partially answered, and therefore I should either clarify my question (by indicating that I would like a blank line to *not* trigger an indent), or accept this answer and start a new question that explicitly mentions @DavidCarlisle 's point regarding blank lines. I'm not sure what  tex.stackexchange protocol is, but I would prefer the former since a new question would be very (too) similar to this question.

Comment: @banbh we should just ping David Carlisle until he posts running code :) I'll message him.

Comment: sigh OK I'll  look later (I had assumed that the commented code was a tested alternative and all I meant in the comment was that should be a better choice, but if it doesn't work I suppose I'd better post a working version:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an answer with \@afterheading ..

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you very much. I was missing the `\@afterindentfalse` and wondered why it did not work.